# Can you add a prefix to controller file names in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I like to name my files with a prefix so that when I have them open in an editor I can distinguish what kind of file I'm working with easily.

So instead of naming the controller file `home.php` or `account.php`, I want to be able to add a prefix to the file name like `controller.home.php`.

Is there a configuration option in Codeigniter that let's you do this?

Comment: If you're having problems determining on what file are you working on, then you're using a wrong IDE and you're not using an IDE at all. Get a proper IDE ;)

Comment: I'm using Sublime text and have recently gone back to Codeigniter for a project. I still encounter this issue when I have a lot of files open it's hard to tell if I'm working with a view, controller or model without a prefixed file name. What IDE would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't such an option, there's no practical reason for it to exist.

Controllers typically extend the CI_Controller class, so that helps you know what type of class you're editing, if that is of any use to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration in code-egniter, i guess.

You can not use "." in name, instead of this you can use naming convention like 
"controller_home.php" or "controller-home.php"
"controller_account.php"

May be this will help.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, you need rewrite CI router according to your logic